# HAProxy roundrobin - Unable to login to application

Tags: haproxy

I have an application that is deployed on tomee server. For load balancing the requests  we have configure HAProxy with '**roundrobin'** algorithm. **But I am not able to login to my application with this algorithm** . In the login page, after entering the application login credentials it is redirected to the same login page. There are no errors in the log.  Where as if I change the algorithm to 'source' , we are able to login to the application. Below is the HAProxy configuration:

```
log         127.0.0.1 local2

chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon
nbproc      1

stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    timeout connect         5000ms
    timeout client          50000ms
    timeout server          50000ms

frontend abc-virtual
         bind 1.2.3.4:1111
         default_backend abc-servers

backend abc-servers
        balance roundrobin
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats uri /haproxy?status
        server abc-qa-server1 1.2.3.4:8080 check weight 40
        server abc-qa-server2 1.2.3.5:8080 check weight 40
```

Comment: Are you getting a 503 error message, or something else? Anything useful in the HAproxy log(s)?

Comment: In the HAProxy logs , 
upon loading the application  there is 304 status code
Also while loggin into the appication there is 302 status code

Comment: A 304 is a not-modified and a 302 is a redirect. What's the Location header of the 302 response?

Comment: Sounds like the application needs stickness... `balance source` would provide that, in a roundabout way.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can only use "source" rather than roundrobin .